# How to check if RDD contains elemets of list or not in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, rdd

I have an List with below values

```
items = [v1,v2,v3]
```

And I have an RDD with below rows

```
RDD = [('R1', {v1, v2}),
('R2', {v3}),
('R3', {v2, v3}),
]
```

Now as an output, I want to check if the RDD value list contains the value of 'items' list or not. I want my output in below syntax. If it contains we add '1' otherwise '0' as value and items element as a key in the dictionary.

```
output = [('R1', {v1, 1}),('R1', {v2, 1}),
('R1', {v3, 0}),('R2', {v1, 0}),
('R2', {v2, 0}),('R2', {v3, 1}),
('R3', {v1, 0}),('R3', {v2, 1}),
('R3', {v3, 1})]
```

How can I achieve this? Thanks.

This is what I have tried.

```
rdd = rdd.flatMap(lambda x: ((x[0], {x[i]: 1}) for i in range(1, len(x))))
```

using this I am getting below given output

```
output = [('R1', {v1, 1}),('R1', {v2, 1}),
('R2', {v3, 1}), ('R3', {v2, 1}),
('R3', {v3, 1})]
```

I only am able to add values which are already present in the RDD list but I also want to add element which are not present and map it to '0'.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and show as what you have tried.

Comment: @oldwooki updated, please let me know if you want to know anything else

Comment: You need to update your example with valid python data structure. Is `{v1, v2}` a set ? that doesn't seem to conform with your example code.

Comment: @Psidom that's a list

Comment: `output = [('R1', {v1, 1}),('R1', {v2, 1}),
('R2', {v3, 1}), ('R3', {v2, 1}),
('R3', {v3, 1})]` is this what you want? or `output = [('R1', {v1: 1}),('R1', {v2: 1}),
('R2', {v3: 1}), ('R3', {v2: 1}),
('R3', {v3: 1})]`?